# Diophantus mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Find a number whose subtraction from two given numbers (say, $9$ and $21$) allows both differences to be squares.  Call the required number $9 - x^2$ so that the condition holds automatically.

Comment: well the original equation based off my notes was to set it up to 12+x^2 = (x-4)^2.... the book says the answer is 35/4.  If you solve the problem for x you get 1/2 but I am not seeing how the answer is 35/4 given that equation?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, either. See my answer.

Comment: well this is a math history course so we are doing it how diophantus would have done it... but still it doesnt make logical sense.

Answer (score 2):

Say that $t$ is such a number. Then $$9-t=u^2$$ and $$21-t=(u+v)^2$$ for some integers $u,v$ with $v>0$. It follows that $$12=(21-t)-(9-t)=(u+v)^2-u^2=(2u+v)v.$$ There are only a few ways to factor $12$ as a product of two integers, and since $12$ is even and $u$ an integer, then $v$ can't be odd. Since $0<v\le v+2u,$ it follows that $v=2$ and $2u+v=6$ (so also $u=2$). Hence, $t=5$ is the only solution.